# Audio recording from two audio input and playing in 2 audio output simultaneously and real time

Tags: linux, operating-systems, microphone, alsa, pulse-audio

I have one Linux Machine with 2 USB speakers and a mic system. I want to record simultaneously from one mic and play in another speaker. Like, MicA recording will be played in SpeakerB and MicB recording will be played in Speaker A simultaneously and in real-time. How is that possible? Please suggest some tutorials or some libraries.

I am able to configure the system to record with one mic and play in 1 speaker, but unable to configure to record from 2 different mics and play in 2 different speakers simultaneously and in real-time.

Comment: We'd need more details on what the mics are & how they connect, but essentially you need a stereo input structure, hardware or software, then just pan each input to one side & each output to the opposite side.

Comment: I am using two USB type headphones with mic available

Comment: I am using Sennheiser PC 8 Over-Ear USB VOIP Headphone with Mic 2 pcs

Comment: Then you should just be able to do it in software. I can't help for nix because I don't know the software options, I'm afraid.

Comment: tell me the software names for any other OS, you are comfortable of. I will figure it out for Unix then.

Comment: For Mac there's the excellent Audio Hijack or freeware Soundflower [getting old] or Blackhole [modern replacement]. Windows has such as Voicemeeter Banana (really;) Audacity is a freeware all-platform audio editor but idk how good its i/o routing is.

Comment: the above is not helpful at all, because I want to record everything from micA and then play at the same time in speakerB and recording from micB will be played at the same time in speakerA. The recording and the playing will be in the same time.

Comment: Input Left/Right, record stereo, output inverted Right/Left. Not seeing how that is not as simple as it gets.